# mongoose filter from subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a `collection` of orders in mongodb which contains an array of sub documents named `line_items`.

I want to search/filter all the orders where the `line_item.code` matches with the provided code.
And I want to access only the matched `line_item` in the Array not complete array.

I am new to mongodb and tried `$elemMatch` and `$filter` but it did not work

Comment: Plz provide sample documents and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without model schema and expected output I think you want something like that

```js
db.collection.find(
{
  "line_items.code": 1
},
{
  "line_items.$": 1
})
```

Using positional operator `$` you can get the subdocument which match the query.

Playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JXp3dxPYFpb)